# How to find all triplet values with 5 digits like 28575 * 3 = 85725

Tags: python-3.x

I can't figure out how to get a list of all triplets from 5 digits
A triplet, in this case, is a number where if you multiply the value with 3, the same digit will come out only with digits in a different order. So if there was one '3' in the first diget, the other digit can only have one '3' too.

I tried many different things with double for loops but I can't figure it out. This is was my last try:

```
def istrip(n):
    one = str(n)
    tri = str(n*3)

    for i in one:

        if tri.find(i) == -1:
            return False
    xl = 0
    yl = 0
    for x,y in zip(one, tri):
        xl += int(x)
        yl += int(y)
        if xl == yl:
            return True
    return False



for i in range(10000,33335):
    if istrip(i):
        print(i,i*3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast and effective way of determining if two numbers are "anagrams" will be to break them into digits, then sort the digits. If the results are the same, then the numbers are made of the same digits. For example:

```
>>> n1 = 28575
>>> sorted(str(n1))
['2', '5', '5', '7', '8']

>>> n2 = 85725
>>> sorted(str(n2))
['2', '5', '5', '7', '8']

>>> sorted(str(n1)) == sorted(str(n2))
True
```

As such:

```
def istrip(n):
    return sorted(str(n)) == sorted(str(n * 3))
```

Comment: great, this is indeed a nice way of solving this